# Branch from master or branch from branch?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, branch

I'm working on a branch (**feature1**) which is branched from **master**.
Feature1 branch has many commits and a lot work has been done.

```
----------- Master
   \---------------- Feature1
```

A colleague needs to do some work that is closely related to branch **feature1**.

Should the colleague branch off from **master** or **feature1**?

Let's say the colleague branches off from **feature1** and creates **feature1_addon**, and work continues in parallel between these two branches. The work continues for weeks in parallel.

```
----------- Master
   \---------------- Feature1
            \----Feature1_addon
```

Eventually these two branches (feature1 & feature1_addon) must be merged into master, how should this be done without losing any work?

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical answer is that it doesn't matter to git where branches are made.  You can make them from whatever commit (reachable from whatever branch(es)) gives you access to the version of the code you need to modify.  Each branch can be merged into any other branch more-or-less independently.

"More-or-less" independently because many people have misconceptions about the relationship between commit and branch that would lead them to think that the merges are not independent.  Consider:

```
X -- x -- x -- x -- x <--(master)
      \
       A -- B -- C -- o -- o <--(feature1)
                  \
                   D -- E -- F <--(feature1_addon)
```

Now you could merge `feature1` to `master`, and you probably know exactly what to expect.

Even if you haven't yet merged `feature1` to `master`, you can merge `feature1_addon` to `master`.  But if you do, it will bring in `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` - not merely `D` thru `F` - because `A` thru `C` *are* in the history of `feature1_addon` but are not yet in the history of `master`.  So even though you may think of `A` thru `C` as "part of the `feature` branch", git sees them as both "reachable from `feature1`" and "reachable from `feature1_addon`", no more belonging to one than the other.

Regardless of the order or timing of merges, you should not be concerned about losing work.

You *should* be concerned about merge conflicts, though, for which reason your branch model (creating potentially-long-lived branches that don't interact until they're finally merged together) is not generally thought of as a best practice.

So the non-technical answer is, while you can branch and merge however you want, you might want to think some more about it.

Exactly what branch strategy would be best for your situation is not something I can determine.  I've found gitflow to be very useful, but it is somewhat heavy-weight if there are just two of you, and it assumes an agile workflow (meaning branches represent small units of work that are merged in pretty frequently).

If you prefer to have long-lived lines of development, you should at least consider periodically merging them into one another, so that they don't diverge too much.  Conflicts will then be merged in manageable doses, and less conflicts will be created than if you develop each thread in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

feature1_addon branch can be created from feature1.
$ git checkout -b feacture1_addon feature1

your colleague can continue work work on addon branch.
you can continue work on feature1.

Once the feature and addon is implemented, Push both branches code to origin.

$ git push origin feature1

$ git push origin feature1_addon

Later any one of you can fetch both branches to your local.

$ git fetch && git checkout "branch to create in local"

Once the branches created in local

Checkout to master

$ git checkout master

$ git merge feature1

$ git merge feature1_addon

While merging if any conflicts came, resolve conflicts and commit the code.

With this process no work will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

First, **the colleague should branch off from `feature1` branch** since he/she needs to do the work related with `feature1` while `feature1` branch is not merge into `master` branch for now.

And yes, both `feature1` and `feature1_addon` branch will be merged into `master` branch eventually. And no matter what’s the merged order, works from the two branches won’t be lost.

**If merge `feature1` branch first:**

```
…---A---B---C----------------J  mater
         \                  /
           D---…---F---…---G    feature1
                    \
                      H---…---I feature1_addon
```

**If merge `feature1_addon` branch first:**

```
…---A---B---C---------------------K  mater
         \                       /
           \            H---…---I feature1_addon
             \         /
              D---…---F---…---G    feature1
```

When you do the secondly merge later, if there has no conflicts (you and the colleague did not change the same files), you can merge directly. Else, you can resolve the merge conflicts (combine the work between you and your colleague) during merge.